# How to pandas-groupby a column and get a specific result per group depending on the values of another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame with two columns: one column is date and the other column contains values True or False.

Assume this code to get the Dataframe:

```
d_range=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2018', end='01-06-2018', freq='0.2D', )
d_range=d_range.date
my_list=[]
for i in range(0,d_range.size):
    if 0<i<18:
       my_list.append(False)
    else:
       my_list.append(True)

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':d_range, 'met criteria':my_list})
df.set_index(['date'])
```

This will give us this DataFrame:

```
print(df)

    date            criteria
0   2018-01-01          True
1   2018-01-01         False
2   2018-01-01         False
3   2018-01-01         False
4   2018-01-01         False
5   2018-01-02         False
6   2018-01-02         False
7   2018-01-02         False
8   2018-01-02         False
9   2018-01-02         False
10  2018-01-03         False
11  2018-01-03         False
12  2018-01-03         False
13  2018-01-03         False
14  2018-01-03         False
15  2018-01-04         False
16  2018-01-04         False
17  2018-01-04         False
18  2018-01-04          True
19  2018-01-04          True
20  2018-01-05          True
21  2018-01-05          True
22  2018-01-05          True
23  2018-01-05          True
24  2018-01-05          True
25  2018-01-06          True
```

I need an outcome that will group by 'date' and if there is at least one True value then the result will be True, otherwise it will be False.
The outcome should look like:

```
      date      criteria
2018-01-01          True
2018-01-02         False
2018-01-03         False
2018-01-04          True
2018-01-05          True
2018-01-06          True
```

Can you suggest some code that will do that, please?

Comment: `df.groupby('date').any()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

d_range=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2018', end='01-06-2018', freq='0.2D', )
d_range=d_range.date
my_list=[]
for i in range(0,d_range.size):
    if 0<i<18:
       my_list.append(False)
    else:
       my_list.append(True)

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':d_range, 'met criteria':my_list})

def True_or_Not(x):
    return x>0
df.groupby('date').sum().apply(True_or_Not)
df

Out [1]:
            met criteria
date    
2018-01-01  True
2018-01-02  False
2018-01-03  False
2018-01-04  True
2018-01-05  True
2018-01-06  True
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and tried it like the following: group_df=df.groupby(['date'])['met criteria'].sum().apply(lambda x: x>0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` method on this. Basically, filter the dataframe using the unique values in your `date` column, then check each resulting dataframe if True exists in the `criteria` column.

Populate a dictionary based on the result, create a new dataframe with `column 1` values equal to your `dates` and `column 2` values equal to the mapped bool values from `your_dict`

```
date_unique = list(set(df['date'].values.tolist()))
your_dict = {}

for d in date_unique:
    test_df = df[df['date'].isin([d])]
    if 'True' in test_df['criteria']:
        your_dict[d] = True
    else:
        your_dict[d] = False

output_df = pd.DataFrame()
output_df['date'] = date_unique
output_df['criteria'] = output_df['date'].map(your_dict)
```

Please note that `'True'` is different from `True`, one is a string and the other is a bool data type in python. Whatever/however you read your `criteria` column in the original dataframe, you should apply the correct type to the condition inside the loop.

Comment: I am using True and not 'True' and, I am not sure why... but this did not work for me, even though I corrected the [date] to ['date'] etc. in your suggestion.
Thanks for the pandas-map method that you mention.

Comment: The `date` inside the loop is a variable `date` not a string, the string part is for the name of your `date column` from your DataFrame. Sorry for the confusion, editing the answer.